# How to set a vertical scroll bar for RadAutoCompleteBox?

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, scrollbar

The question is pretty self-explanatory and so what I will write up for it is the 2 things that I have tried already which didn't work. So that we can eliminate some of the possibilities.

1) I have tried setting a ScrollViewer that wraps RadAutoCompleteBox

`<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
   ...The Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox element
</ScrollViewer>`

Didn't work.

2) Search for this on Google and the answer was pretty much setting MaxDropDownHeight to a certain number but that only does it for the drop down and I want the scroll bar to be available for the actual TextBox that you type into.

Thank you so much for your time everyone!

Comment: Anyluck with this?